# JAVA: How to get the max timestamp with streams max?

Tags: java, timestamp, java-stream

I have a list of timestamps and I need to get the latest timestamp.

The solution below works in one of our system's newer environment, but doesn't work with the older environment. The compiler of the older environment doesn't accept the method reference "::" inside max().

```
var latestTimestamp = timestamps.stream().max(Timestamp::compareTo);
```

Is there any alternative ways without using "::"?

Comment: `Comparator.naturalOrder()`?

Comment: the "older environment" what version of java it uses?

Comment: Do you mean `java.sql.Timestamp` class?

Comment: `Timestamp latestTimestamp = Collections.max(timestamps);`? Beware that it will throw `NoSuchElementException` if the list is empty, so check for that first.

Comment: Regarding "compiler of the older environment doesn't accept", what *exactly* do you mean by "doesn't accept"?

Comment: Your older compiler is probably Java 1.7 or older, meaning it also doesn’t accept `var` nor streams. And meaning that while you should use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your timestamps, you will need to do that through [the ThreeTen backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
timestamps.isEmpty() ? null : Collections.max( timestamps )
```

Full example for Java 7 and earlier:

```java
List < Timestamp > timestamps = new ArrayList <>();
timestamps.add( Timestamp.valueOf( "2023-01-23 12:00:00" ) );
timestamps.add( Timestamp.valueOf( "2023-01-23 23:00:00" ) );
timestamps.add( Timestamp.valueOf( "2023-01-23 01:00:00" ) );

Timestamp latestTimestamp = timestamps.isEmpty() ? null : Collections.max( timestamps );
```

> 2023-01-23 23:00:00.0

## Details

Let's make some example data.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2023 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
List < Timestamp > timestamps = List.of(
        Timestamp.from( ZonedDateTime.of( ld , LocalTime.MAX , z ).toInstant() ) , // Convert from modern class to legacy class.
        Timestamp.from( ZonedDateTime.of( ld , LocalTime.MIN , z ).toInstant() ) ,
        Timestamp.from( ZonedDateTime.of( ld , LocalTime.NOON , z ).toInstant() )
);
```

> timestamps.toString() = [2023-01-23 14:59:59.999999999, 2023-01-22 15:00:00.0, 2023-01-23 03:00:00.0]

### Java 8+, streams & lambdas

Java 8 brought major new features including lambdas, streams, method references, and `var`. Let's use those.

```
var latestTimestamp = timestamps.stream().max( Timestamp :: compareTo );
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/vRqncy).

> latestTimestamp.toString() = Optional[2023-01-23 14:59:59.999999999]

### Java 8+, conventional style

We can convert that code to conventional style. Your IDE such as IntelliJ may offer to automate the conversion.

Here is the result of IntelliJ 2022.3 converting for me.

```java
boolean seen = false;
Timestamp best = null;
for ( Timestamp timestamp : timestamps )
{
    if ( ! seen || timestamp.compareTo( best ) > 0 )
    {
        seen = true;
        best = timestamp;
    }
}
var latestTimestamp = seen ? Optional.of( best ) : Optional. < Timestamp > empty();
```

The [`var`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/286) is new in Java 9+. For Java 8, replace with `Timestamp` declaration.

When run, same result.

> latestTimestamp = 2023-01-23 14:59:59.999999999

### Prior to Java 8

We can further modify that code for before Java 8. Neither [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) nor [`var`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/286) are supported in Java 7 and earlier.

```java
boolean seen = false;
Timestamp best = null;
for ( Timestamp timestamp : timestamps )
{
    if ( ! seen || timestamp.compareTo( best ) > 0 )
    {
        seen = true;
        best = timestamp;
    }
}
Timestamp latestTimestamp = best;
```

As [commented by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861923/java-how-to-get-the-max-timestamp-with-streams-max/73862166#comment130426798_73862166), we can further simplify even in earlier versions of Java.

Use [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) to find the largest by [natural order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Replace the entire block seen above with this one-liner. The [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) (`?:`) is a compact alternative to an if-else statement.

```java
Timestamp latestTimestamp = timestamps.isEmpty() ? null : Collections.max( timestamps );
```

---

By the way, you are using *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To represent a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

To represent a moment to be exchanged with a database systems via JDBC 4.2 and later, use [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for a column of a type akin to the SQL Standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

For Java 6 and Java 7, add the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project to get most of the *java.time* functionality back-ported. But those versions of Java are long past their end-of-life; consider upgrading to a [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java: 8, 11, or 17.

Comment: Prior to Java 8, you can not use `var` (in fact, even Java 8 does not support this). Besides that, even then, there was no need for manual loops, `Timestamp latest = timestamps.isEmpty()? null: Collections.max(timestamps);` Generally, I consider it preferable to use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, instead of creating new comparators with `…::compareTo` for already `Comparable` types.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your Comment. I used that to improve the Answer.